# Does not match when the string does not have a dot but it will match multiple dots

Tags: regex

I am trying to match the string when there's 0 or multiple dots. The regex that I can only match multiple dots but not 0 dot.

```
(\w*)((\w*\.)+\w*)
```

These are the test string I am using

```
dial.check.Catch.Url
dial.check.Catch.Url.Dial.check.Catch.Url
32443.324342.23423424.23.423.423.42.34.234.32.4..2..2.342.4
234dfasfd2aa4234234.234aa341.4.123daaadf.df.af....
12fd.dafd
.
abc
```

The Regex will match these

```
dial.check.Catch.Url
dial.check.Catch.Url.Dial.check.Catch.Url
32443.324342.23423424.23.423.423.42.34.234.32.4..2..2.342.4
234dfasfd2aa4234234.234aa341.4.123daaadf.df.af....
12fd.dafd
.
```

But not this one:

```
abc
```

https://regexr.com/?38ed7

Comment: What about `[\w.]+`?

Comment: @ctwheels Would match `a.b.c` which isn't what OP is after?

Comment: Why do you need a regex? Just count the number of occurrences of `.` in the string. If you get to the end without seeing any, return true. If you get to the end with seeing only one, return false. If you ever find the second dot, get out early and return true. You may have other requirements that demand a regex, but for something this simple, I'd just write code.

Comment: @user268396 how do you know?

Comment: Does it? I'm confused? Do you want to match a string with zero dots or not? `[\w.]+` requires there to be a dot in the string. Also by using `\w` you are restricting yourself to American letters and numbers and underscores only. It doesn't match strings with non-ASCII letters or even symbols.

Comment: `[\w.]+` will match `abc`. See [my solution below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49182260/3832970).

Comment: @ctwheels Actually `[\w.]+`  will match all the parameters I am looking for. https://regexr.com/3m02o

Answer (score 0):

If you really must use a regex, here is one (but it is inefficient):

```
/^(?![^.]*\.[^.]*$).*$/
```

It says:

> Match a string so that the beginning of the string is *not* followed by a whole string with a single dot.

It does some backtracking when parsing the negative lookahead.

As mentioned in the comments to the question, I do think, unless you *must* have a regex, that a simple function might be better. But if you like the conciseness of a regex and performance is not a huge concern, you can go with the one I gave above. Regexes with "nots" in them are generally a tad messy, but once you understand lookarounds they *do* become doable. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

`/\..*\.|^[^.]*$/`

Or, in plain English:

> Match EITHER a dot, then any number of characters, then another dot; OR the beginning of the string, then any number of non-dots, then the end of the string.

Comment: Very nice. Better than mine, though to make it quicker maybe the first `.*` could be either `.*?` or `[^.]*`.

Comment: This is wrong because `^[^.]*$` part matches `abc`. See OP: *But not this one: `abc`*

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: You and I have differing interpretations of the question. I interpreted the _But not this one: `abc`_ as referring to the regex that OP had supplied, `(\w*)((\w*\.)+\w*)`. Unfortunately it's hard to tell what's "correct".